# In 1.11, how do you summon a Skeleton Trap?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In 1.10, I was using the command:

```
/summon EntityHorse ~ ~1 ~ {SkeletonTrap:1b,SkeletonTrapTime:1b}
```

I like that this command creates the trap "naturally". So, in 1.11, how does this convert? I am **not** looking for the command that just spawns a jokey like:

```
/summon minecraft:skeleton_horse ~ ~1 ~ {Tame:1,Passengers:[{id:"minecraft:skeleton"}]}
```

I am looking for the "real" thing like the example at the top of the paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 1.11, skeleton horses are now summoned with `skeleton_horse`. The `SkeletonTrap` tag will still work:

```
/summon skeleton_horse ~ ~1 ~ {SkeletonTrap:1b}
```

Comment: Perfect...that helps!